# What happens when an UIView is added to another UIView twice in IOS?

Tags: ios, uiview

What happens when an UIView is added to another view twice in iOS? I believe it wont get added twice. Have anyone ever tried?

Comment: I believe he means, what happens when a view is added to the SAME view twice, (ie literally calling view.addSubview(otherView) twice)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`[UIView addSubview:]` documentation

> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview.

Comment: Beware that there is a difference between an explicit removeFromSuperview, then re-add vs. directly calling [UIView addSubview]. Touch events will be canceled in the former, but not in the latter approach.

Comment: What if that view is the receiver? That's the question. You're not answer the original question.

Answer (score 1):

A view can only have one parent view. But a view can have many subviews.

Read the Documentation of [UIView.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-DontLinkElementID_7)

Specifically read about **addSubView**

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you alloced an UIView twice, the old object has been retained by superView.

for example

```
UIView *viewA = [UIView new];
[superView addSubview:viewA];
viewA = [UIView new]; //there is a new object.
[superView addSubView:viewA];
```

another example, when implement `init` and `initWithFrame` method both.

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *subView;
@end

@implement MyView
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.subView = [UIView new];
        [self addSubview:self.subView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.subView = [UIView new];
        [self addSubview:self.subView];
    }
    return self;
}
@end

//init will call initWithFrame with CGRectZero automatically, subView alloced twice.
MyView myView = [[MyView alloc] init];
```